# How can I write a symmetrical version of a snap to value formula (in C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, equation

I would like to write a component that can move a value up by an increment amount, or move to the nearest increment.

Assuming the increment was 0.0005, for an Up() method, here would be the expected inputs and outputs:

- 1.0005 -> 1.0010 (at increment so it moves by the increment)
- 1.0006 -> 1.0010 (not at increment, so moves to increment)
- 1.0007 -> 1.0010
- 1.0008 -> 1.0010
- 1.0009 -> 1.0010
- 1.0010 -> 1.0015 (at increment so it moves by the increment)
- 1.0011 -> 1.0015
- 1.0012 -> 1.0015
- etc

And the Down() method would do the same, in reverse.

I have come up with this formula for up:

`return (value + increment) - (value % increment);`

I expected that the Down() method would be similar but I can't find what it is. The only way I've been able to get it to work is by doing:

```
decimal mod = value % increment;

return mod != 0  ? value - mod : value - increment
```

Surely if the operation is the same in reverse, then the formulas should be the same.

Comment: You could create a function which has all values enumerated and simply find closest to a given in the up/down direction (which you can choose).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static decimal Increment(decimal dec, decimal inc) {
        var mod = (dec % inc);
        return dec - Math.Abs(mod) + (inc < 0 && mod != 0 ? Math.Abs(inc) : 0) + inc;
    }
```

Without the ternary operator:

```
    public static decimal Increment(decimal dec, decimal inc) {
        var mod = (dec % inc);
        var signInc = Math.Sign(inc);
        return dec - Math.Abs(mod) + 
              ((decimal)(Math.Pow(signInc, 2) - signInc) / 2) * 
                    Math.Abs(Math.Sign(mod)) * 
                    Math.Abs(inc)
                + inc;

    }
```

---

```
  ((decimal)(Math.Pow(signInc, 2) - signInc) / 2) * 
                    Math.Abs(Math.Sign(mod)) * 
                    Math.Abs(inc)
```

replaces the ternary expression. `Math.Pow(signInc, 2) - signInc) / 2` returns 1 if `inc` is negative and 0 otherwise. `Math.Abs(Math.Sign(mod))` returns 0 if `mod` is 0 and 1 otherwise; making the result of the first multiplication 1 if `inc < 0 && mod != 0` and 0 otherwise.

Comment: That definitely works for both, thanks! Is there a way of doing it without using the ternary operator? I'm just curious more than anything. Just seems like if the ternary is not necessary for Up, it should be necessary for Down either?

Answer (score 0):

formula

```
value - Abs(value % increment) + Abs(increment/2) + increment/2
```

take value 1.0006 as example with increment (+_)0.0005

when up increment is +0.0005

```
1.0006-0.0001+0.00025+0.00025 = 1.0010
```

when down increment is -0.0005

```
1.0006-0.0001+0.00025-0.00025 = 1.0005
```

Comment: I assumed that `Down(1.0006)` should give `1.0005`, not `1.0000`.